# How can I find a limit to this sequence? It contains floor function

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (2+\sqrt3)^n - \lfloor(2+ \sqrt3 )^n\rfloor = 1$$ I don't know how to find a limit with $ n \to \infty $ plus I've got floor function in it. Any help I'd appreciate :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Math.SE! Please show us what you have tried, for one. Second, as a hint, note that, if $ a \in \mathbb {R}^+ $, then $ a - \lfloor a \rfloor = \{ a \} $, where $ \{ a \} $ is the decimal part of $a$. Gintas K.'s hint is very helpful from here.

Comment: you will have to prove that $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ converges nearly to an integer value. is that possible?

Comment: How do I find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \{(2+\sqrt3)^n\}$ ? I have tried all basic methods from L'Hopital's rule (but I don't know how to transform it to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form). Thank you soo much

Comment: Also I have tried binomial expansion but it doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Think about adding $(2-\sqrt{3})^n$, as $(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ is always an integer, and take limits.

Comment: Okay thank you freak_warrior your hint is very useful.
I have got it now that the problem equals to
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \{(2+\sqrt3)^n\} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \{(2+\sqrt3)^n +(2-\sqrt3)^n - (2-\sqrt3)^n\}= \lim_{n\to \infty}1-(2-\sqrt3)^n = 1$$

Thank you so much everyone :)

Comment: @user108292 Your proof is a bit flawed, the above limit in your comment is definitely not 1.

Comment: Isn't if $$p = (2+\sqrt3)^n + (2-\sqrt3)^n$$, then p is always positive integer and   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \{(2+\sqrt3)^n + (2-\sqrt3)^n - (2-\sqrt3)^n\}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \{p - (2-\sqrt3)^n\} = \lim_{n\to \infty} 1 - (2-\sqrt3)^n = 1 - \lim_{n\to \infty} (2-\sqrt3)^n = 1$$ Where did I go wrong?

Comment: To user108292: I think a little more explanation is needed. If $p$ is a positive integer and $0 < \delta < 1$ then $\{p - \delta\} = \{p - 1 + 1 - \delta\} = 1 - \delta$. Here $\delta = (2 - \sqrt{3})^{n}$.

Comment: @user108292: refer to user1734134's answer for an explanation. Anyway accept my answer? :)

Comment: To freak_warrior: as explained in my previous comment I think OP (and user1734134 also) has made right use of your hint.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$a - \lfloor a\rfloor$ is the same as $a$ mod $1$

Comment: Still I don't know what to do with $\lim_{n\to \infty} (2+\sqrt3)^n\ mod \ 1$ .What I know is that $\sqrt3$ is irrational so I thought it was divergence for a second but actually it was convergence to 1. Still don't get it. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

$$(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n - \lfloor(2+ \sqrt3 )^n\rfloor = 1$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n - \lfloor(2+ \sqrt3 )^n\rfloor = 1$$
Now,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(2-\sqrt{3})^n=0$$,
so we will obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(2+\sqrt{3})^n - \lfloor(2+ \sqrt3 )^n\rfloor = 1$$

Comment: This is the proper proof! Brilliant!